# Firestore error 'Requested Entity not found' in swift app

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm getting this error:

`[Firebase/Firestore][I-FST000001] WriteStream (129e2dd38) Stream error: 'Not found: Requested entity was not found.'`

in my app built on SwiftUI and i cannot seem to find any information relating to this error and firestore.

for context: this is an app for a dog walker, Dogs have a many-to-many relationship with Customers. this particular bit of code is supposed to add a list of DocumentID's from the `dogs` collection

when a dog is added to Firestore, a `Dog` object is added to a `Customer.dogs`
and then this function is called, passing in the `Customer` in quesiton

```
func saveDogsTo(_ customer: Customer){
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        print("saveing listed dogs to \(customer.id)")
        var ids: [String] = [String]()
        for dog in customer.dogs{
            print("Appending id: \(dog.id)")
            ids.append(dog.id!)
        }
        
        db.collection("customer").document(customer.id!).updateData(["dogs": ids])
    }
```

The print statements are showing the correct information, all the ID's exist on Firestore (I've checked), and this is not down to `dogs` being missing from a customer's document (only cause i could think of, but i tried running this code on documents with and without existing `dogs` fields)

I'm at a dead end here so can anybody see my mistake?

Happy to provide any extra information as required. Just ask :)

Thanks

Comment: How consistently do you get this error and can you confidently attribute it to any particular block of code? And does the error occur in both simulators and physical devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the benefit of anyone else with a similar error.

I was trying to update a document in the `customer` collection, however the collection was actually called `customers` meaning Firestore was looking in the wrong place for the document

Anybody else with this error should check all their collection references are spelled correctly -_-